# Arrange two unequal length arrays based on id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

Array 1:

```
[{Id:1,Name:'abc'},{Id:5,Name:'bcd'},{Id:3,Name:'xyz'}]
```

Array 2:

```
[{Id:3,Name:'Ajay3'},{Id:5,Name:'Ajay5'},{Id:1,Name:'Ajay1'},{Id:2,Name:'Ajay2'},{Id:4,Name:'Ajay4']
```

On re-arranging the two arrays the output should be like:

Array 1:

```
[{Id:1,Name:'abc'},{Id:3,Name:'xyz'},{Id:5,Name:'bcd'}]
```

Array 2:

```
[{Id:1,Name:'Ajay1'},{Id:3,Name:'Ajay3'},{Id:5,Name:'Ajay5'},{Id:2,Name:'Ajay2'},{Id:4,Name:'Ajay4'}]
```

OR

```
[{Id:1,Name:'Ajay1'},{Id:3,Name:'Ajay3'},{Id:5,Name:'Ajay5'},{Id:4,Name:'Ajay4'},{Id:2,Name:'Ajay2'}]
```

Let me know the best way for above. The existing IDs in both array should be in same order and the extra Ids in one of the array should be in the last.

Comment: On what basis do you want to sort the second array? It does not seem to follow any order.

Comment: @Saravana On the basis of only existing Ids.

Comment: Okay. So where are you stuck? What part are you having trouble with? Right now, this reads as "please do my work for me."

Comment: best option create jsfiddle first !!!

Comment: In your first array sorted, the ids are 1, 3, 5 ... got it.  In the second sorted, the ids are 1, 3, 5, 2, 4 or 1, 3, 5, 4, 2 ... that's not in order.

Comment: @rfornal The extra ids which are 2,4 not present in the first array should be present in the last in any order.

Comment: @zooney [edit] your questions and update such information there. Are the common objects in both array **same** or different..?

Comment: I don't know why do this question is put on hold?! It is clear, the question's owner want to sort data!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```js
var Arr1 = [{Id:1,Name:'Ajay1'},{Id:5,Name:'Ajay5'},{Id:3,Name:'Ajay3'}];
var Arr2 = [{Id:3,Name:'Ajay3'},{Id:5,Name:'Ajay5'},{Id:1,Name:'Ajay1'},{Id:2,Name:'Ajay2'},{Id:4,Name:'Ajay4'}];

var finalArr = [];
var unMatchedArr = [];
Arr2.forEach(function(item) {
  var inArr = Arr1.filter(function(a1) {
    return a1.Id === item.Id;
  });

  if(inArr.length) {
    finalArr.push(item);
  }

  else {
    unMatchedArr.push(item);
  }

});

var finalArr = finalArr.concat(unMatchedArr);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(finalArr));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

finalArr contains the results

Comment: Can I suggest `some` rather than `filter`, no reason to create a resulting array just to use its length.

Comment: This also doesn't put the first three entries in the correct order. Very good of you to try to do the OP's work for them, though.

Comment: Guys both the arrays need to rearranged based on existing Ids.And the above solution is not correct.

Comment: @zooney: Again: **What part** are you stuck on ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : the existing Ids in both the arrays should be in same order .

Comment: @zooney: Again:: What part are ***you*** stuck on? Make an effort, and if you run into a problem, ask a specific question about that problem.

Comment: The code does for the most part, just tweak it to make it work. Totally agree with @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :: Im stuck with finding the easy way to do the above.

Comment: @zooney: Due respect, I'm not seeing any effort. Mark's already done more than enough of the work for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Well to make it more clear , the rearrangement makes the first array , a sub array of the second array with extra elements at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) to sort the first array.

Then combine [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and [every](http://underscorejs.org/#every) to find the remaining ones. Finally you can create the second array by combining both arrays using the native [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method as shown below:

```js
var arr1 =[{Id:1,Name:'abc'},{Id:5,Name:'bcd'},{Id:3,Name:'xyz'}],
arr2 = [{Id:3,Name:'Ajay3'},{Id:5,Name:'Ajay5'},{Id:1,Name:'Ajay1'},{Id:2,Name:'Ajay2'},{Id:4,Name:'Ajay4'}],
  newArr1 = _.sortBy(arr1, "Id"),
  diff = _.filter(arr2, function(obj) {
    return _.every(arr1, function(elm) {
      return elm.Id != obj.Id;
    });
  }),
  newArr2 = newArr1.concat(diff);

console.log(newArr1,newArr2);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newArr1));
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newArr2));
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

You can also do the same the *other way* combining [reject](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) and [some](http://underscorejs.org/#some) as well:

```js
var arr1 = [{Id:1,Name:'Ajay1'},{Id:5,Name:'Ajay5'},{Id:3,Name:'Ajay3'}],
  arr2 = [{Id:3,Name:'Ajay3'},{Id:5,Name:'Ajay5'},{Id:1,Name:'Ajay1'},{Id:2,Name:'Ajay2'},{Id:4,Name:'Ajay4'}],
  newArr1 = _.sortBy(arr1, "Id"),
  diff = _.reject(arr2, function(obj) {
    return _.some(arr1, function(elm) {
      return elm.Id == obj.Id;
    });
  }),
  newArr2 = newArr1.concat(diff);

console.log(newArr1, newArr2);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newArr1));
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newArr2));
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

**Update:**

```js
var arr1 =[{Id:1,Name:'abc'},{Id:5,Name:'bcd'},{Id:3,Name:'xyz'}],
arr2 = [{Id:3,Name:'Ajay3'},{Id:5,Name:'Ajay5'},{Id:1,Name:'Ajay1'},{Id:2,Name:'Ajay2'},{Id:4,Name:'Ajay4'}],
  newArr1 = _.sortBy(arr1, "Id"),
  matches = _.filter(_.sortBy(arr2, "Id"), function(obj) {
    return _.find(arr1, function(elm) {
      return elm.Id == obj.Id;
    });
  }),
  diff = _.difference(arr2, matches),
  newArr2 = matches.concat(diff);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newArr1));
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newArr2));
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @T J : Please look into my edited question. Your solution would work for arrays having same items ,but in my case the objects can have different values.

Comment: @zooney The solution will still work for your edited array, as long as they should be sorted according to `Id` property. The objects can have any number of other properties having different values...

Comment: @T J : Nopes, it wont work for objects having different values. It is concatenating the newArray1 to diff.

Comment: @zooney I updated the first demo with the new *updated* arrays and it works fine. Note that you're missing an `}` in second array.

Comment: @T J : Output should be -Array1 [ abc(id:1),xyz(id:3),bcd(id:5)] and Array2 [Ajay1(id:1),Ajay3(id:3),Ajay3(id:5),Ajay2(id:2),Ajay4(id:4)] .Items having common ids are in same order and new items in second array can follow any order.

Comment: @zooney see the update. FYI, edits invalidating the existing answers are not encouraged in SO, and can be rolled back. So re-read your question and make sure it clearly conveys what you want to do **before posting**, so that it doesn't waste others time and you can avoid such discussions...

Comment: @zooney and did the answer help..?